# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, github, ionic-framework, grpc

I'm trying npm install on my ionic angular project. All I'm getting is this error.

```
command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp 
install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using Node 16.14.2
and npm 8.5
and angular version 14.
windows 11

I tried

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install grpc -g
```

nothing is working.

I stuck on this for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

The `grpc` library has been deprecated for over 2 years, and it is not compatible with Node 16. The recommended replacement is `@grpc/grpc-js`.